# I am getting error about clearRect (canvas in html)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want an image to fall from the top and clear the entire canvas when the condition is true. everything is fine until `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);`
inactive. please help me. Thank you in advance. Here is my code

```
let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image;
img.src = "./img/l1.png";
c.width = 300;
c.height = 600;
let s = setInterval(() => {
        if (yBlock + Math.max(y1, y2, y3, y4) * 30 > 570) {
            clearInterval(s);
            yBlock -= 1;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        }
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 600);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.drawImage(img, xBlock * 30, yBlock, xSize, ySize);
        ctx.closePath();
        yBlock += 1;
    },
    1);
```

Comment: Hard to say since this isn’t minimum reproducible code. I do believe though that even though you clearInterval that setInterval will finish running. So in your code it will continue to drawImage and then clear.

Comment: I got it, I moved the if to the bottom and it was successful. thank you very much

Comment: Good to hear that it worked